# Execute a goal from commandline in all submodules

Tags: maven, maven-2

this is a snippet from a multi-module parent pom. How can I run a goal in all submodules of the project?

```
<modules>
    <module>../utp</module>
    <module>../testdependency</module>
</modules>
```

When I try to run this goal by `mvn -am -pl utp help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId`, I'll only get the result for the parent pom, I don't get any result for the utp and eventual dependencies.
How can I run a goal on all submodules of a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html), we could use `help:evaluate` *to evaluate some Maven expressions*.

This works in an interactive way or takes `artifact` and `expression` as parameter. It reports the result for the project if run on the project pom or the `artifact` if run without a pom.

It is not meant to give the artifact details for all dependencies.

Not sure what your requirement is... If it is to get the various dependency details, you could try one of the goals of [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/), like `mvn dependency:list` or `mvn dependency:tree`.  If it is to know if the versions of the dependencies are upto date, you could try a goal in [versions maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) like `mvn display-dependency-updates`.

**Edit:**

Plugins which are defined in `<pluginManagement`> section of *parent* pom are run only in those modules, where these `<plugins>` are declared.  In other modules, they are not run.  Perhaps [mvn help:effective-pom](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/usage.html) can give some info.

Comment: basically, I want to find out, which of the goals of maven plugins are ran once for every module and which are ran only once. For example, there's the `exec-maven-plugin`, when I execute it's `exec` goal, it will run once in every module, on the other hand, if I create some executable java class and run the `java` goal, I can't persuade the maven to run in every module, it runs just once, in parent. So I want to find out, how to control this.